# LINEログインで公開設定ができません

Tags: ios, line

iOSアプリにLINEログインを実装しようとしていますが、現在テスター権限のLINEアカウントしかログインができません。
公開の設定を行いたいのですが、申請画面も設定も見当たらず、公式のドキュメントやいろんな記事を調べたのですが去年からか仕様が変わっており見つかる記事通りに進めることができません。

手順をご存知の方がいらっしゃればお教えいただきたいです。

Answer (score 1):

現状勝手に公開済みにステータスが変更されており、テスターではなくともログインできるようになっていました。
比較的新しいチャンネルのものはステータスが非公開のままで、どういうフローで公開設定に切り替わったかは分かりません。